Creation of Alert rule for the device onboarded to SCOM?
We have successfully onboarded an Eaton UPS device to SCOM monitoring tool. However, when there is a battery discharge or if we do a test trap within the device console its showing under SNMP trap in SCOM but not triggered as an alert. Is  possible to create a generic rule that trigger as a alert for the above scenario?
Deployed the management pack for the UPS in SCOM
Succesfully onboarded the device
Done a test trap within UPS console, showing in SNMP trap in SCOM but not triggered as alert
